# Converting string to a dictionary and make is subscriptable

Tags: python

I am quite new to python and today I found someone who used dictionaries in a neat way to store multiple values whilst still being able to easily access them. I then got the idea of utilizing this method where the dictionaries almost branch off like a tree. I then stumbled into the problem where I can't use the value of `firstKey` to read the next dictionary (either `dict3` or `dict4`). With no luck from google have I found a way to change `firstKey` from type `str` to `dict`.

```
from random import *

dict1 = {
    'coords': (173, 34),
    'branches': 1,
    'dict2': 4

}

dict2 = {
    'coords': (254, 213),
    'dict3': 2,
    'dict4': 2

}

dict3 = {
    'coords': (371, 224)

}

dict4 = {
    "coords": (239, 327)

}

randomNumber = randrange(1, 3)

firstKey = list(dict2)[randomNumber] # the result will be a string with the same name as either dict3 or dict4
print(firstKey)
print(type(firstKey))

#print(firstKey["coords"]) This is what is not working since firstKey is a string
```

Comment: Your `dict`s don't reference the other `dict`s you're creating, so `firstKey` would end up being `2` in your example (since those are the values you've assigned to the `'dict3'` or `'dict4'` keys of `dict2`).

Comment: And how would one go about and fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list` at

```
firstKey = list(dict2)[randomNumber]
```

is senceless because simple call of `dict2` itself returns a list of `dict2`'s keys. So, yes, `firstKey` will be a **string** with one from the values: "`coords`", "`dict3`" or "`dict4`".
However, there are `dir()` function that returns a list of the names of all variables and `eval()` thar returns a value of a variable by ir's name. Try to use them.